# What is faster to execute - expr or if

Tags: tcl

I am looking at the possibility of optimizing the execution of some of my existing code using ternary operators in single command containing if and else blocks.

Is the ternary operator approach faster than the traditional if / else e.g which is faster to execute of the following:

First:

```
expr {[info exists arr($var)]? [return $_timeouts($var)] : [puts "No key $var has been set"]}
```

Second:

```
if {[info exists arr($var)]} { 
    [return $_timeouts($var)]
} else {
    puts "No key $var has been set"
}
```

Notice that the entire expr in the ternary operator approach (First) is contained in a single {} block and I am hoping this will be faster to execute than the Second approach.

Thanks

Comment: There is a mistake in the `if` variant: there shouldn't be brackets inside the braces for the true clause. When that is corrected, both variants are compiled to almost identical byte code (in both cases, the selection structure is replaced with jumps), with the most significant difference being that the `expr` variant has to execute `tryCvtToNumeric` before terminating, most likely costing some execution time.

Comment: The execution time differences are minute, and will depend a lot on the exact patchlevel of Tcl. There are some subtleties in there, of which `tryCvtToNumeric` is only one. But it's really not worth worrying about unless you've _proved_ that it is a bottleneck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built-in [time](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/time.htm) command to test your question.

I changed 'puts' to a different 'return' statement so that the speed of a variable that exists in the array could be directly compared to the speed of a variable that does not exist in the array.

```
variable arr

proc test1 { var } {
  variable arr

  expr {[info exists arr($var)] ? [return $arr($var)] : [return -1]}
}

proc test2 { var } {
  variable arr

  if { [info exists arr($var)] } {
    return $arr($var)
  } else {
    return -1
  }
}

proc init { } {
  variable arr

  # fill arr with stuff...
  for {set i 0} {$i < 10000} {incr i} {
    set arr($i) $i
  }
}

init
puts [time {test1 9000} 10000]
puts [time {test1 15000} 10000]
puts [time {test2 9000} 10000]
puts [time {test2 15000} 10000]
```

The results on my machine:

```
bll-tecra:bll$ tclsh t.tcl
1.3121 microseconds per iteration
1.0267 microseconds per iteration
1.1399 microseconds per iteration
0.9029 microseconds per iteration
```

So using expr is a bit slower.  In this case, the more readable code is definitely a win.

The speed difference is pretty small.  If this small of a difference is affecting your program, I also recommend trying this code with a dictionary rather than a array and check the speed differences.